# Logstash: Remove Subdomain with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, logstash, gsub

I have same domain name in my logs:

```
queryname= domain.com
queryname= sub1.domain.com
queryname= sub-2.sub1.domain.com
queryname= suB3.sub-2.sub1.domain.com
```

I want to get in logstash only domains without subdomain. How can do it in mutate [gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub)?

Trying to do like this but it doesn't work

```
mutate { 
  gsub => [ "queryname", "(?!([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})$)", "" ]
}
```

a little bit confused, will be happy any advice. thanks

Comment: To confirm, you only want the first query to be selected, yes? Or do you want to select `domain.com` from every single one of those queries?

Comment: "domain.com" (Second-level domain) from every string

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
queryname=\s*([\w-]+\.)*(\w+\.\w+)$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tY7vR5/2)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
queryname=\s*        # 'queryname= ' Part
(                    # Sub-Domains
    [\w-]+               # Letters
    \.                   # . (Dot)
)*                       # Sub-Domains are Optional
(                    # domain.com
    \w+                  # Letters (domain)
    \.                   # . (Dot)
    \w+                  # Letters (com)
)
$                    # ... String ends with Sub-Domain
```

The domain will be stored in the **2nd Group**

Comment: Sorry, but in logstash it get all the line, doesn't split subdomains.